# Applescript: Select a finder folder using part of a string

Tags: variables, applescript, directory, finder

I'm looking for a way/code to select a folder within a specific folder that contains part of a string from a variable

I have folderA and within folderA are numerous folders. All the folders within folderA start out with a 5 digit number followed by an "_" and then a short description. ie, 12345_Folder Test 1, 54321_Folder Test 2, 99999_Folder Test 3, etc...

```
    tell application "Finder"
        set folderA to folder "FolderA" of folder "Desktop" of folder "MacUser" of folder "Users" of startup disk
        set jobNum to text returned of (display dialog "Enter 5 Digits Only:" default answer "")
        open folderA
        set selected_item to (folder whose name contains jobNum in folderA) -- This is what's failing for me. 
-- from here on I would like to do other things such as run other parts of a script.
end tell
```

---Script Error Message

> Can’t get folder whose name contains jobNum of folder "FolderA" of
>   folder "Desktop" of folder "prepress_js" of folder "Users" of startup
>   disk of application "Finder". ----

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this line:

```
set selection to item 1 of (get every folder in folderA whose name contains jobNum) -- This is what's failing for me.
```

Comment: Thank you for the response Craig! I tweaked it a little and now it's working as intended.   --set selection to get every folder in folderA whose name contains jobNum

Comment: Great news. Will you please mark the answer as correct?